# In iOS 17, edit widget menu, how to remove a selected item from second selection menu

Tags: ios, widget

I want to create a widget with edit functionality.

There are multiple choosing option.

If a user select an item from first selection,I want to remove it from second selection.

Once again, if a user select an item from second selection, I want to remove it from first selection.

How can I do it?

I have used DynmaticOptionsProvider but I don't know how to catch the selected item